# Drawing Library: Dynamically drawing different markers in Google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I am using Google maps api 3 to allow user to dynamically draw markers to the map using the Drawing tools. (ref. [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools))

I want the user to be able to draw multiple markers **having different icons**.
For e.g, he should be able to draw a school marker, a hospital marker, etc. Each of the icon will be different.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/wiki/HowToAddNewIcons#Your_Google_Map_could_look_like_this) is what I want the user to draw.

In the docs, it shows that all the markers will have the same icon.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var drawingManager;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({});
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000),
        zoom: 4
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        markerOptions:{
            draggable: true,
        },
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
            ]
        }
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
        var latlng = event.overlay.getPosition()
        console.log(latlng);
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

});

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update the `markerOptions`-property of the `DrawingManager`-instance with the desired [`Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

Basic usage:

```
drawingManagerInstance.setOptions({markerOptions:
                                       {icon:'path/to/another/marker.png'}});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/A2Xhv/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/A2Xhv/)

Comment: In that case, all the markers will have the same icon. I want to draw multiple types of markers on the same map.

Comment: No, they wouldn't. As soon as a Marker has been drawn he is not affected by changes of markerOptions

Comment: Am quite not getting it. I have updated my code. Do you mean to say that in the markerOptions, i should specify icon: 'link_to_my_image' ?

Comment: not directly in the markerOptions, when you like to do have different markers you must update the markerOptions dynamically(e.g. based on a user-selection) via [`setOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager)